# How to crop image using the Opencv's convexHull coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, contour, convex-hull

So I am writing a small program to crop the white part of a license plate (check image). I succeed in finding the white rectangle using an HSV mask (with low and white colours) and by filtering the size of the contours. Nevertheless using:

[This is the image i use as a base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmCKA.png) (i am covering the numbers for privacy reasons)

```
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
```

It gives a rectangle which crops a larger part of the license plate (when the plate is sideways). For this reason I used the following after the filtering:

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(contour)
cv2.drawContours(copy, contours=[hull],
                                 contourIdx=0,
                                 color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
```

This marks the correct area on the picture as seen below:

[white marked area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJhcR.png)

Now my main problem is how can I crop only the marked part that was detected using the convexHull functions. I am quite new to the world of computer vision but I could not find something that could help me but from what I understand through my experiments with HSV and HSL I need to create a mask which will crop focus only on the specific area of the image but how can i create a mask from the hull result?

using the boundingRect method i normally do:

```
# img_plate is the original image
img_plate[y:y + h, x: x + w]
```

But this will crop a larger image and not the one i really need.

Thank you in advance for all your answers.

Comment: set `thickness=-1` so that the contour is filled. then use that as a mask.